# Android Phonegap navigation and keep loading functions running across pages

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html-frames

Ok, so I've looked around a bit and am hoping someone can help me on this one. I'm developing an app that manages a bunch of little small applications. One of the applications interaction with a service that returns JSON info. The problem is, when someone refreshes to re-acquire the info, the service takes about a minute to process and then returns. It would be silly to assume the user will wait on that screen for all that time.

My question: How can I let the user hit the refresh button on that page and navigate around the rest of the app while that call is still processing and the user can go back to it whenever he/she wants. I've looked into frames and I think that may be where I will end up but I know very little about them so my research is very immature.

Has anyone dealt with this and can give me some info or pointers in a different/right direction?

Comment: look into `localStorage`. When they hit the page, if it's stored locally, load it from local storage, otherwise fire off the request (asynchronously, of course, storing the data locally and displaying it when it comes back).